# JavaScript While Loops

Tags: javascript, while-loop, increment

I (very) recently started JS after previously studying python, and after completing a CodeCademy exercise, I tried to experiment a little with incrementation in a while loop.

```
let hungerLevel = 5

while (hungerLevel < 9) {
  if (hungerLevel > 7) {
    console.log('Time to eat!');
  } else {
    console.log('We can eat later!');
    hungerLevel += 1;
  }
}
```

Syntax for this will probably be covered soon enough in the course, but I'm curious as to why my code throws an infinite loop. Surely the loop should break after 3 'We can eat later!'s (6,7,8) and one 'Time to eat!' (9)?

I know it can't be right, but I don't see why it's not.

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pen and write down each execution step…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you get into the

```
if (hungerLevel > 7) {
    console.log('Time to eat!');
}
```

you never increment your `hungerLevel` so the rest time your `hungerLevel` stays to `8` and you get infinite loop.

Use like this, increment every time

```js
let hungerLevel = 5

while (hungerLevel < 9) {
  if (hungerLevel > 7) {
    console.log('Time to eat!');
  } else {
    console.log('We can eat later!');    
  }
  hungerLevel += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing `hungerLevel` only if it 7 or less. You should move `hungerLevel += 1;` after `else` block.

Comment: Wow, how did i miss that? -.-

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your increment out of the if statement

```
while (hungerLevel < 9) {
  if (hungerLevel > 7) {
    console.log('Time to eat!');
  } else {
    console.log('We can eat later!');
  }
  hungerLevel += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an increment variable starting with a specific value, increment it during each loop, and check if it reaches an ending value, the `for` loop is the right tool for the job.

```
for (let hungerLevel=5; hungerLevel < 9; hungerLevel++) {
  if (hungerLevel > 7) {
    console.log('Time to eat!');
  } else {
    console.log('We can eat later!');
  }
}
```